# SQL query discard records with multiple entries

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to find a query to resolve my issue:

i have something like this on my database:

[image]

i need a query that selects all users that have role 5 but if for some reason they have any other role it should skip them

```
SELECT user_id FROM user_table WHERE roleid = 5 AND (roleid != 3 OR roleid != 1)
```

That still returns user 64

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are looking for a `not exists` clause:

```
select *
from t
where roleid = 5 and
      not exists (select 1 
                  from t t2
                  where t2.user_id = t.user_id and t2.roleid <> 5
                 );
```

Alternatively, if you are just looking for such users, then you can use `group by` and `having`:

```
select user_id
from t
group by user_id
having min(roleid) = max(roleid) and min(roleid) = 5;
```

(If `roleid` could be `NULL`, the logic would need to take this into account.)

Comment: LEDGEND! that not exists works like a charm! Thank you!